# NASA GLAS Lidar Data Format

Tags: remote-sensing, land-surface, data-formats

NASA GLAS Lidar Data can be downloaded [here](http://nsidc.org/data/icesat/data.html).

I cannot find (or perhaps understand) the answer to my question on the icesat/glas page.  Lidar data can be provided as points (las) or raster (dem), though I believe either could be packaged as HDF5 (what they offer).  They list a number of parameters which makes it sound like it's points, but then they compare results with an SRTM dem.

Does anybody know what you get with this download?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the specific dataset your are wondering about?

Comment: http://nsidc.org/data/icesat/data.html

Comment: Now I realize the data size (only a few MB) tells me it's all raster.

Comment: @casey, you don't know if there is GLAS xyz data available anywhere?

Comment: You might want to put this question to http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @JKelly Which dataset on that page? There are many.

Comment: Right.  I don't know which dataset, because I'd want xyz points and can't identify which might be that (currently thinking none are).

Comment: Raster surely represents (grid) points, anyway? Even if it's points that represent areas...

Comment: Yeah, but they're aggregated.  You can't, for example, get a meaningful point density or height percentiles over a region.

Comment: *my question on the icesat/glas page.*  ??